# Dropzone.js Installation with NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: dropzone.js, dropzone

I've "Installed" the Dropzone.js package through package manager in Visual Studio 2019 for a project in asp.net core 2.2. However, I'm not finding the js file anywhere in the project tree, nor does dropzone seem to be functioning in any manner.  Do I have to ignore the nuGet package and just download the js file manually? Or is there something else I'm missing?

I was able to make it work by downloading dropzone.js (and associated files) directly from the dropzone repository. Just not through the NuGet package.

Thanks,
Owen